# Multi-column enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol

Is there a simple way to produce a 2-column enumerated list like this:

```
a. A short bit of text          d. And so on
b. Another short bit            e. Down to ...
c. Yet another                  f. The end
```

I've looked at the `multicol`, `tasks`, `shortlist`, and `paracol` packages, but they all have issues that make them less than ideal for my purpose. Does anyone know of a way to do this that would make it easy for me to use? I'm in the process of writing a text so I'll be using a fair number of these. In an ideal world, the solution should involve little more work than the standard enumerate environment.

Comment: try `\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}`

Comment: `Shorlst` is rather easy to use. What's not working with it? It has the advantage, as `tasks`, to number  items *horizontally*, which makes the list easier to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Down-To multicolumn enumerate lists are easy -- horizontal ones require the task package.

I've used the `multicol` package and `\begin{multicols}{2}...\end{multicols}` for this (two columns)

In order to change the enumeration labels, it's quite easy to use `enumitem` (or `enumerate`, with another syntax, however)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*.}]
\item This 
\item starts
\item here
\item and 
\item goes
\item down
\item and so on
\item[]
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If there is an odd number of `\item` it's possible to fool `enumerate` by using `\item[]` to get an empty item entry and keep the alignment.

[image]

Comment: Down to lists are easy when you have an *even* number of (rather similar) items. Add an item `\item and up` to see the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: True... unfortunately...